# iMac audio input port stopped working

Tags: imac, audio, microphone

**Setup:**
headphones --> iMac -> amp -> microphone

(The Amp, cords, and microphone all work fine as do all elements of the DAW *garage band*).

**History:**
We were successfully using an [iMac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201896) connected through the line-in audio to a Europower Amp (pmp560m) + microphone to record songs in Garage Band.  Everything was working great ... until we plugged headphones into the Mac so that we could stack record *(record a track while listening to a previously recorded track)*.

Recording and playback worked splendidly until the headphones were unplugged.  When they were unplugged we lost audio playback on the entire mac.  *(This issue was resolved by checking audio settings, closing programs and restarting the computer).*

**The Current Problem:**
Now everything works as usual except for the line-in audio port.  So we are unable to record.

When I checked the Mac settings for audio Line-in, it has a pulse, but is seemingly erratic.  Moving the slider on "Output volume" doesn't do anything.

[image: AudioInput]

The input for recording tracks in Garage Band read the same, and there is a constant low-level wave (sounds like white noise) when we try to record.

**The problem seems to be the line-in port.**

Does this port just burn out with time?

Why would plugging in headphones while recording cause this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help on this!